# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fonts, assets

As the title suggest, the font file seems that can't be found. 
I quote the error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found
>   fontawesome-webfont.ttf"

The code is:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(assets, "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        Button button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnIniciarSesion);
        button.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
    }
}
```

The font file is in the assets folder, as you can see in the following image:

[image: font file inside assets folder]

What can I try?

Comment: Is the font Build Action set to AndroidAsset? Another problem could be that the way you are typing the font might not actually be the name of the contained font. For example, I use the Segoe font in my Xamarin apps and the UISegoe named font lives in the UISegoeRegular.ttf. You can figure this out by opening the font in a font viewer like http://us.fontviewer.de/

Comment: @BrewMate i tried with your suggestion and didn't work. The font Build Action was in AndroidAsset by default. So I tried with the name of the font like in a font viewer is shown ("FontAwesome") and the issue persist.

Comment: I do this in my code and it works for me: 
`Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset ("SegoeUI", "SegoeUIRegular.ttf");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
```

Comment: "CS0103 The name 'getContext' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1):

you should set in "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" file properties -> build Action and choose AndroidAsset

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and created again the solution and the problem has 'magically' disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

try this instruction it work for me

```
Typeface oswaldFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Oswald.ttf");
```